# python panda join dynamic columns by removing duplicates

Tags: python, performance, pandas, string-concatenation

we have an use case where we need to join all column values in a row by removing duplicates.Data is stored in a data frame of panda.
For eg consider below data frame df  with columns A,B,C

```
A   B   C   
X1  AX  X1
X2  X2  X1
X3  X3  X3
X4  XX  XX
```

I would like to add a new column which concatenates A to B to C and remove duplicates if any found by preserving the order. The output would be like

```
A   B   C   Newcol

X1  AX  X1  X1_AX
X2  X2  X1  X2_X1
X3  X3  X3  X3
X4  XX  XX  X4_XX
```

Note that the number of columns are dynamic. 
As of now I am doing it by using the command

```
df.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.dropna().astype(str).drop_duplicates()),axis=1)
```

But this is very slow and takes around 150 seconds for my data.
But since 90% of the data frame are usually with only 2 columns , I put an if statement in my code and run the below command for cases with 2 columns

```
t1=pd.Series(np.where(df.iloc[:,0].dropna().astype(str) != df.iloc[:,1].dropna().astype(str), df.iloc[:,0].dropna().astype(str)+"-"+df.iloc[:,1].dropna().astype(str),df.iloc[:,1].dropna().astype(str)))
```

which takes around 55.3 milli seconds

or even

```
t1=df.iloc[:,0].dropna().astype(str).where(df.iloc[:,0].dropna().astype(str) == df.iloc[:,1].dropna().astype(str), df.iloc[:,0].dropna().astype(str)+"-"+df.iloc[:,1].dropna().astype(str))
```

both consumes almost same time ( 55 ms opposed to 150 seconds ), but issue is that it is applicable only for 2 columns.
I would like to create a generalised statement , so that it can handle n number of columns.
I tried using reduce on top ,but it gave  error while i tried for 3 columns.

```
reduce((lambda x,y:pd.Series(np.where(df.iloc[:,x].dropna().astype(str) != df.iloc[:,y].dropna().astype(str), df.iloc[:,x].dropna().astype(str)+"-"+df.iloc[:,y].dropna().astype(str),df.iloc[:,y].dropna().astype(str)))),list(range(df.shape[1])))
```

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Please note that the df is actually a chunk of a multicore parallel task. So it would be great if the suggestions excludes parallelism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
df['new'] = df.astype('str').apply(lambda x: '_'.join(set(x)), axis = 1)

    A   B   C   new
0   X1  AX  X1  AX_X1
1   X2  X2  X1  X1_X2
2   X3  X3  X3  X3
3   X4  XX  XX  X4_XX
```

EDIT: Maintain the order of the column values

```
def my_append(x):
    l = []
    for elm in x:
        if elm not in l:
            l.append(elm)
    return '_'.join(l)


df['New col']=df.astype('str').apply(my_append, axis = 1)

1000 loops, best of 3: 871 µs per loop
```

Returns

```
    A   B   C   New col
0   X1  AX  X1  X1_AX
1   X2  X2  X1  X2_X1
2   X3  X3  X3  X3
3   X4  XX  XX  X4_XX
```

EDIT 1: In case you have nan in any column like this

```
    A   B   C
0   X1  AX  X1
1   X2  X2  X1
2   X3  X3  X3
3   NaN XX  XX
```

Handle that in the function and then apply

```
def my_append(x):
l = []
for elm in x:
    if elm not in l:
        l.append(elm)
l = [x for x in l if str(x) != 'nan']
return '_'.join(l)

df['New col']=df.astype('str').apply(my_append, axis = 1)


    A   B   C   New col
0   X1  AX  X1  X1_AX
1   X2  X2  X1  X2_X1
2   X3  X3  X3  X3
3   NaN XX  XX  XX
```

Comment: sorry , but as i mentioned , i need to preserve the order. setting key.index on set gives error and does not have much time benefit either

Comment: Wow. that did do the trick , the new code takes only 2 seconds compared to 150 seconds. Thanks. One doubt . how about the dropna() ? shouldn't that be added along?

Comment: to avoid chances of "nan" being one of the values, i used      df.fillna('').astype('str').apply(hutils.dup_remove, axis = 1)  .  And in the if clause added " and elm !=  ''

Comment: That works but if you compare the time, handling it in list takes 887 µs per loop while fillna('') solution is 1.83 ms per loop

Answer (score 1):

`pd.unique` doesn't sort.  Use it wrapped in a comprehension

```
df.assign(new_col=['_'.join(pd.unique(row)) for row in df.values])

    A   B   C new_col
0  X1  AX  X1   X1_AX
1  X2  X2  X1   X2_X1
2  X3  X3  X3      X3
3  X4  XX  XX   X4_XX
```

---

Handle NaN

```
df.assing(new_col=[
        '_'.join(pd.unique([i for i in row if pd.notnull(i)])) for row in df.values
    ])
```

Comment: it does not handle NaN.

Comment: it works now. Thanks .  %timeit took around 2.71 seconds